# How to add curl encode space in url shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

In application when we create project with the name like example:

Test project or demo checking getting error i.e., with the space having in between them is not taking and its working like example demo or test or link

Below is my script I'm getting one issue with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Begin
TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "username:,password:" -- -- "$@")

    [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

    eval set --  "$TEMP"

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
             case "$1" in
                    --username) TS_USER="$2"; shift;;
                    --password) TS_PWD="$2"; shift;;
                    --) shift;;
             esac
             shift;
    done


curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${TS_USER}'", "password": "'${TS_PWD}'"}' https://example.com/login

echo "generated token is:" $token

curl --location --request POST "https://example.com/" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" 

echo "runId =" $runId

if [ -z "$runId" ]
then
          echo "RunId = " "$runId"
          echo "Invalid runid"
          echo $(curl --location --request POST "https://example.com/" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"")
          exit 1
fi


taskStatus="WAITING"
echo "taskStatus = " $taskStatus



while [ "$taskStatus" == "WAITING" -o "$taskStatus" == "PROCESSING" ]
         do
                sleep 5
                 echo "Checking Status...."

                passPercent=$(curl --location --request GET "https://example.com/" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"")

                    

                        taskStatus="${array[0]}"

                        echo "Status =" "${array[0]}" " Success Percent =" "${array[1]}"  " Total Tests =" "${array[2]}" " Total Failed =" "${array[3]}"



                if [ "$taskStatus" == "COMPLETED" ];then
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
                       
                        echo  "Run detail link https://example.com${array[7]}"
                        echo "-----------------------------------------------"
                        echo "Job run successfully completed"
                        exit 0

                fi
        done

 
echo "Task Status = " $taskStatus
 exit 1
fi

echo "$(curl --location --request GET "https://example.com/" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"")"
exit 1

return 0
```

1. The following command throwing error because of space having

   ```
   bash script.sh --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --project Test Project
   ```
2. The following command working because in between space I add `%20`

   ```
   bash script.sh --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --project Test%20Project
   ```
3. The following command working because of single work or name I given

   ```
   OUTPUT COMMAND:- bash script.sh --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --project Test
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it helps in any way.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Begin
TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "username:,password:,project:,profile:,scanner:,emailReport:,reportType:,tags:" -- -- "$@")

    [ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

    eval set --  "$TEMP"

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
             case "$1" in
                    --username) FX_USER="$2"; shift;;
                    --password) FX_PWD="$2"; shift;;
                    --project) FX_PROJECT_NAME="$2"; shift;;
                    --profile) JOB_NAME="$2"; shift;;
                    --scanner) REGION="$2"; shift;;
                    --emailReport) FX_EMAIL_REPORT="$2"; shift;;
                    --reportType) FX_REPORT_TYPE="$2"; shift;;
                    --tags) FX_TAGS="$2"; shift;;
                    --) shift;;
             esac
             shift;
    done

FX_SCRIPT=""
if [ "$FX_TAGS" != "" ];
then
FX_SCRIPT="&tags=script:"+${FX_TAGS}
fi

token=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "'${FX_USER}'", "password": "'${FX_PWD}'"}' https://example.com/login | jq -r .token)

echo "generated token is:" $token

URL="https://example.com/api/v1/runs/project/${FX_PROJECT_NAME}?jobName=${JOB_NAME}&region=${REGION}&emailReport=${FX_EMAIL_REPORT}&reportType=${FX_REPORT_TYPE}${FX_SCRIPT}"

url=$( echo "$URL" | sed 's/ /%20/g' )

runId=$(curl --location --request POST "$url" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '.["data"]|.id')

echo "runId =" $runId
if [ -z "$runId" ]
then
          echo "RunId = " "$runId"
          echo "Invalid runid"
          echo $(curl --location --request POST "$url" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '.["data"]|.id')
          exit 1
fi


taskStatus="WAITING"
echo "taskStatus = " $taskStatus



while [ "$taskStatus" == "WAITING" -o "$taskStatus" == "PROCESSING" ]
         do
                sleep 5
                 echo "Checking Status...."

                passPercent=$(curl --location --request GET "https://example.com/api/v1/runs/${runId}" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token""| jq -r '.["data"]|.ciCdStatus')

                        IFS=':' read -r -a array <<< "$passPercent"

                        taskStatus="${array[0]}"

                        echo "Status =" "${array[0]}" " Success Percent =" "${array[1]}"  " Total Tests =" "${array[2]}" " Total Failed =" "${array[3]}" " Run =" "${array[6]}"



                if [ "$taskStatus" == "COMPLETED" ];then
            echo "------------------------------------------------"
                       # echo  "Run detail link https://example.com/${array[7]}"
                        echo  "Run detail link https://example.com${array[7]}"
                        echo "-----------------------------------------------"
                        echo "Job run successfully completed"
                        exit 0

                fi
        done

if [ "$taskStatus" == "TIMEOUT" ];then
echo "Task Status = " $taskStatus
 exit 1
fi

echo "$(curl --location --request GET "https://example.com/api/v1/runs/${runId}" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"")"
exit 1

return 0
```

Then run your command.

```
bash job_script.sh --username "USERNAME" --password "PASSWORD" --project "Test Project"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```sh
bash job_script.sh --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --project "Test Project"
```

inside script I asuume it is best to use different options flag i.e:

```sh
TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "username:,password:,project:,project-spaced:,profile:,scanner:,emailReport:,reportType:,tags:" -- -- "$@")
.
.
.
--project-spaced) FX_PROJECT_NAME="$2 $3"; shift 2;;
```

Comment: that will work but i want to be  added in script and that will be temporary solution i want to have permanent in script

Comment: I assume as the space character is considered a separator you can only use a different method to call the scripts that has space in between their names, otherwise the extra word after the space is left alone so your function breaks. or maybe you could always use two-part names for your projects with this method.

Comment: got error after adding --project-spaced) same i have add like u show me ..here is the error arse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 20
bash job_script.sh --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --project-spaced Test Project even after adding this not work and also i add this line in script project-spaced:,profile; not working  i think $3 what it do dont know

Comment: where to add --data-urlencode and -G in above script i try but couldnt understand it where it need to add so that project name should show like this test%20project

Comment: `TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "username:,password:,project:,project-spaced:,profile:,scanner:,emailReport:,reportType:,tags:" -- -- "$@")` in your first line

Comment: `$2` picks the first word `$3` picks the second word, and save them inside single variable named: `FX_PROJECT_NAME`

Comment: I did that already again i try but got same error here is what i make changes in script plse have a look at below
TEMP=$(getopt -n "$0" -a -l "username:,password:,project-spaced:,profile:,scanner:,emailReport:,reportType:,tags:" -- -- "$@")

                    --password) FX_PWD="$2"; shift;;
                    --project-spaced) FX_PROJECT_NAME="$2 $3"; shift 2;;
and got error below is that error
Invalid runid
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 20
 
and there is add in output command --project-spaced Test Project